# Lock object onto single face of mesh - Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to lock the position of an object (Blue arrow) onto a single face of another object (Red Square) so that it follows it's rotation exactly

Usually I am able to do this with a 'sample nearest surface' node setup like below:

[image]

but in this case I seem to be getting misalignment happening - particularly when I flip the object upside down? Could this be because I'm using shape keys to deform the mesh or am I missing something else?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

[image]

Comment: i am sorry....where is the misaligning? don't see it  -> i just ran the animation of your example file

Comment: You can see in the GIF the Blue arrow rotates around like a compass - whereas I'm wanting it to stay locked with the orientation of the Red plane

Comment: do you want it like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfypI.gif

Comment: yeah that's it! but just facing down so the arrow is flat and parallel with the grey/red surface (Like in my first picture)

Comment: this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUCEx.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, i hope i got what you want. Try this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: yeah thanks that pretty much does it - still a tiny bit of misalignment at the end but I guess that's just because my mesh face is so distorted? https://imgur.com/a/6pl1AVf

Comment: might be the reason. I am not sure.

Comment: @JaRa ... works for me whole animation (I don't see any distortion ... just for arrow pointing down I revert Indexes from 1, 2, 3 to 3, 2, 1